# Getting key from json using jsonpath not working

Tags: jsonpath

input json

```
{
"1212": [
  {
    "size": "M",
    "colour": "RED"
  },
  {
    "size": "L",
    "colour": "BLUE"
  },
  {
    "size": "XL",
    "colour": "GREEN"
  }
  
]
}
```

I want here ***1212*** as output using jsonPath.

I tried jsonpath as `$.*~` which works online jsonpath evaluator and give result as `[1212]`.

But when i use same jsonpath in my code it doesn't work. Ex -

```
JsonPath.read("jsonobject", "$.*~");
```

I get output as

```
[
  {
    "size": "M",
    "colour": "RED"
  },
  {
    "size": "L",
    "colour": "BLUE"
  },
  {
    "size": "XL",
    "colour": "GREEN"
  }

]
```

Dependency for jsonpath in my code

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: https://jsonpath.com/ uses [JSONPath Plus](https://github.com/JSONPath-Plus/JSONPath#jsonpath-plus-)

Comment: Use https://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/ to test online for [Jayway JSONPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath).  The closest alternate is [`keys()`](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#functions) function, but it may not be helpful in this particular case unless you have included only some part of json.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to change the **JSON** to make it as an array you can extract the key using `keys()` function.

**JSON**

```
[{
    "1212": [{
            "size": "M",
            "colour": "RED"
        },
        {
            "size": "L",
            "colour": "BLUE"
        },
        {
            "size": "XL",
            "colour": "GREEN"
        }
    ]
}]
```

**JSONPath**

```
$.[*].keys()
```

[image: JSONPath]